# Adding JScrollPane to a JPanel without a Layout Manager

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

Before I start, I'm aware that its a bad idea to not use a Layout Manager and usually I do use one, however, I also have all my components automatically re-size and relocate based on the size of the window. In addition the program I'm working on is only intended to run on 1 machine throughout its entire lifetime. Please don't downvote me just because of lack of layout manager, I found it to be what I need for this particular program.

To my issue, I found a similar post on stackoverflow but a solution was never achieved.
I'm adding a dynamic amount of `JLabels` to my `JPanel`, I've noticed that when not using a layout manager, the scroller doesn't work.

This is a simplified version of my initialization code.

```
JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
mypanel.setLayout(null);
mypanel.setSize(800,450);
mypanel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
mypanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
scrollablePanel = new JScrollPane(mypanel);
scrollablePanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollablePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,300));
scrollablePanel.setSize(800,300);
scrollablePanel.setLocation(250,156);
myContainer.add(scrollablePanel);
```

where `myContainer` would be the container (also without a layout manager). The `JLabels` are added later on to the `JPanel` with:

`enter code here`mypanel.add(label1);

after some basic settings are set for the labels such as `setForeground` and `setBackground`.

Unfortunately when run, the scrollbar appears as if its not required (see image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEl5O.png

The table text seen in the image is made up of multiple `JLabels`.
If it's not possible to resolve the issue without using a Layout Manager I will switch to BoxLayout, I was just hoping there would be a solution.

Comment: `JScrollPane` relies on the result from the view's `getPreferredSize` method, which relies on the `LayoutManager`...

Comment: So it would not be possible to make it work, or is it possible to set PrefferedSize manually?

Comment: @alex2410 But it will never show a scroll bar scrubber...

Comment: The short answer is not really. Seriously, a simpler solution would be to make use of an appropriate layout manager or three or even just use a `JTable`...

Comment: Ahh I see,
`myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,450));`
appears to work but I see where the issues will arise later.
Thanks for your help. If you want you can write and official answer and Ill select it as the correct answer for anyone that runs into similar situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `JScrollPanel` needs the preferred size of the view component to determine when the view exceeds the scroll pane's viewable area.

The preferred size of a component is normally determined via the layout manager.  While you can use `setPreferredSize`, it is typically discouraged and you will simply run into the same problem as the content exceeds what ever value you decide to set.

A better solution would be to use a `LayoutManager` or compound layout (using multiple layout managers over multiple containers) to achieve the result you desired...or write your own...